# Can not create two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

what's wrong here?
 table foreign doesn't appear?
i can't create two tables in one database or what!!

```
use orders;
create table prim(
    order_id int auto_increment ,
    order_date date,
    constraint pr_orders primary key(order_id)
     );

    create table foreign(
    orderid int not null,
    ordername varchar(15),
    orderdescribtion varchar(200),

    constraint fk_orders foreign key(orderid)
     references prim(order_id)  

    );
```

Comment: `foreign` is a reserved word, like in `foreign key`...

Answer (score 1):

`FOREIGN` is a reserved word in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-F